# Lookup filter Inclusion (Incorrect type. Record Type not compatible with Text)

Tags: apex, lookup, relationships, configuration, lookup-filter

I have a **object b** which has lookup to **object a**. when i prompt to create a new record in **object b** i will select the record type and then i will go to edit page.
Now when i click the lookup icon of **object a** , the records should be filtered based on record type selection of object b.
For this i have created text field in object a with the record type name.

```
How to apply lookup filter on the Object A Lookup.
```

> Error:
>
> Incorrect type. Record Type not compatible with Text

Answer (score 0):

While creating the Lookup for Object A you should also configure the Lookup filter. In your case the Object A is going to be the child of Object B. So while creating the Lookup relation field for Object A in the Object B, please configure the Lookup filter correctly.

Comment: That I did, But I need to know condition for filtering records in the lookup filter.